# How to scale and draw and Audio Buffer to a Canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas, scaling, web-audio-api

Im trying to visualize the waveform data of an audio buffer to a html5 canvas.

I used `buffer.getChannelData(0)` to get the value for each sample.
And then i drew each sample value to the buffer using a for loop.

Its working now, but the problem is it uses each pixel for a sample which means it requires 44100px sized canvas to draw one second of audio.

this is the code im using to draw:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(i, height / 2, 0.5, (data[i] * height));
        }
```

And you can see the whole code here
http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/KKNFL/1/

How can i scale it so it fits the the `canvas.width` according to the loaded buffer size every time a buffer is loaded?

Thanks

Comment: The following example code from mdn seems to do what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Visualizing_Audio_Spectrum

Comment: @markE This is about spectrum analysation and visualisation. My question is about waveform data visualisation. I found a code that does it https://github.com/cwilso/Audio-Buffer-Draw but did not understand how he did the scaling.

Comment: I'm not an audiophile, so sorry, your distinction just flew right over my head :(   But..it seems from their code that they sort the large incoming data into bins and just display the aggregated bin information rather than every single datapoint.  That's how they dealt with their scaling issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your canvas has a width of 500, and your audio is 60 seconds long with a sample rate of 44100 kHz...

What you need to do is figure out how many samples are going to represent a single pixel on your canvas. To do that, you basically say `var binSize = ( audioBuffer.duration * 44100 ) / 500;`

Now you iterate over all the samples and group them into sections of `binSize` length. For each bin, you find the max value and push it into an array. Once you're done, you'll have an array with 500 values that you can use to draw into your canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your JSFiddle and posted a fork here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jjDpm/4/

Here's the key line:

```
ctx.lineTo(i, height/2 + data[step*i] * amp);
```

The problem with scaling on the X-axis is resolved by coming up with a "step" factor and then using that to move through the data at an appropriate rate. The idea is that you won't be able to graph every single data point, but you'll essentially graph an evenly (step) spaced set of samples from the data.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a simple ADSR synth, allowing the user to enter the parameters for an instrument that will then be synthesized, making it's data available for visualization or playback. I also used 44100 hz.

The key to getting a good looking image, is to realize that you don't want to plot just once for each horizontal pixel, but rather once for each sample. In the case of say a 0.2s sample and a 256px wide canvas, you'll need to fit 8,820 samples into 256 pixels - ~34 samples per pixel. It seems like overkill, but it's the only way to get a visualization that doesn't miss data. It's also the way to get an image that resembles those found in sound-editing programs, eg Audacity, Milkytracker etc, etc.

Here's a hi-hat drum, Fmax > 10,000 hz
[image: Visualization of a hi-hat drum - Fmax = > 10,000 hz]

**EDIT:** image added to show that calling closePath does not add a line from the end-point back to the starting point.

[image]

Here's the visualization code I use:

```
function drawFloatArray(samples, canvas)
{
    var i, n = samples.length;
    var dur = (n / 44100 * 1000)>>0;
    canvas.title = 'Duration: ' +  dur / 1000.0 + 's';

    var width=canvas.width,height=canvas.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#303030';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,height/2);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x = ( (i*width) / n);
        y = ((samples[i]*height/2)+height/2);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    canvas.mBuffer = samples;
    canvas.onclick = function() { playSound(this.mBuffer, 44100, 50); };
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you should be using `ctx.closepath()` - that command draws a line from the final point to the initial starting point, useful for closing loops and stuff like that. In most cases you probably won't see that extra line because the 1st and last point are usually zero, but in some cases you'll get a weird line connecting the beginning of the waveform to the end

Comment: @GershomMaes - I am, and no, it doesn't necessarily act like this at all. Since stroke was called first, the path is not modified by this line that you suggest. Failing to call closePath means that the canvas has an open path with a large number of line-segments in it. You can see an extra image I've added to the original post that demonstrates this. :) - You can see a live demo of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/rsNZB/ - If you change the 800 on line 222 to a 700, you'll get the image I've shown. Sadly, deprecation of webkitAudioContext means the code no longer plays audio.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a sample library to do this: https://github.com/cwilso/Audio-Buffer-Draw.

Comment: i actually ended up using your library. but given that you are not drawing all samples ( as far as i understand ), this might be a problem if you want to use it in a audio editing scenario which you want to have sample accurate interface. I tried drawing all the samples on fractions of pixels here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/yxCAU/), But i have not figured out yet how to zoom in. But the selection tool is working now.

Comment: any other suggestions on how to make an audio editing interface?And here is link btw: http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/yxCAU/1/

Answer (score 0):

The solution written by: enhzflep
Is the correct way, but with audio files with large audio buffer arrays, you will need to chunk the processing when iterating over the audio array's buffer length to prevent crashing the browser. Rather than using a setTimeout, set a variable to a value that can be checked once the the chunk process is completed. The way I did it was like this:

```
 function processChunk(ctx, cwidth, cheight){

    var chsize = 6000;
    var index=0;
    var chComplete;

    function doChunk(){

        var chunk = chsize;

        while(chunk-- && index<data.length){

            var x = (index*cwidth)/data.length;
            var y = ((data[index]*cheight/2)+cheight/2)
            ctx.lineTo(x,y);
            index++;
            chComplete=1;

        }

        chComplete=0;

        if(index < data.length){

            function checkChunk(){
                if(chComplete==0){
                    doChunk()
                    console.log('chunking');
                }else{

                    setTimeout(checkChunk(), 500);  
                }
            }

            checkChunk();
        }


    }

    doChunk();

}
```